# Can we skip a java @AfterClass method in testng xml

Tags: java, testng, skip

I have a testng java class with some test having @BeforeClass and @AfterClass. I use xml to run this testng class. Some time I may need to skip @AfterClass which usually has clearing of the testbed.

How can we achieve this to skip only the @AfterClass

Comment: Why do you have a @AfterClass block which should be called after the unit test is done when you actually do **not** want it to be there? If you don't want it can't you simply remove it? Please explain in detail which test and preparation/cleanup code should be called and which shouldn't (and why).

Comment: Some scenarios in my case I want to skip the afterclass which clears the data on testbed. So instead of having a separate class having no AfterClass, I want to reuse the same by just skipping it

Comment: Shouldn't these tests be in a class without an `@AfterClass`, which then wouldn't cleanup the testbed? It would sound difficult to maintain the tests when the `@AfterClass`, which should be called after the test with the class is done, does in fact not get called.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using TestNG listeners for this. For example, we could have a following test class `com.example.SampleTest`:

```
public class SampleTest {

  @BeforeClass
  public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("Executing before class method.");
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void tearDown() {
    System.out.println("Executing after class method.");
  }
}
```

To disable execution of `@AfterClass` method you can create a listener `com.example.AfterClassListener` like this:

```
public class AfterClassListener implements IAnnotationTransformer2 {

  @Override
  public void transform(IConfigurationAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    if (annotation.getAfterTestClass()){
      annotation.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
}
```

After that add this listener to your `testng.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="test-suite" verbose="1" thread-count="3" parallel="none">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.example.AfterClassListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="Login Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.example.SampleTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Whenever you want to enable it back just remove this listener from `testng.xml`

Comment: great let me try this out

Answer (score 0):

> Some scenarios in my case I want to skip the afterclass

So put the "some scenarios" in a conditional

```
@AfterClass
public void after()
{
    if (something)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can be done this way, But can't we do it in testng xml file?

Answer (score 0):

If it is pre-decided  i.e. before the suite starts to run, you know you want to clear or not, you can control it with parameter/system properties.
Put parameter  in your xml file and turn true and false based on what you need to do.  You can even read it from system variables.

Your @AfterClass can check

```
if (toDeleteDb) -> clear -> else return (do nothing)
```

If it is at runtime, then set a property and replace the if condition with that property.

Answer (score -1):

@BeforeClass is called once before the start of all test similarly @AfterClass is called only once after all tests are executed. Thus adding scenarios checks in @AfterClass method makes no sense as it is last method that will be execute in your junit class and program exits. 
It at all you want to check for certain conditions before/after each @Test execution use @Before/@After